# Angular 8 Injectable Globals does not maintain value

Tags: angular, angular8

I have declared a `global.ts` file:

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  utentePuntoVendita: boolean = false;
[...]
}
```

In the constructor of my components I read this variable and do something. The first component that is loaded correctly reads it. Then if I navigate to another component (from the first one, so a second page level) I can see that the value in globals is inverted.

How is that possible?

I've checked and I've never reassign the value in globals, I only read it.

This is how I read it:

```
constructor(
    private global: Globals
  ) {
    this.utentePuntoVendita= this.global.utentePuntoVendita;
}
```

I've tried to print global in console and I've noticed something very strange:

[[image]]

and this is for every console.log of global, in every component. But only the first one is somehow capable of reading the correct value. What's happening?

Comment: Try https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#using-providedin. Or place code for NgModules where you provide Globals service

Comment: Decorate it with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` and do not provide it in any providers array.